# ¿Como arrastrar elementos desde un div a otro y obtener numero de ordenamiento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

necesito mover elementos(se muestran los nombres de las preguntas) desde un div derecho a uno central:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando esten en el div central deben desplegarse las preguntas relacionadas a ese elemento arrastrado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo recuperar, además de los datos de los formularios, el orden en que se insertaron las preguntas.

¿Alguien me podría dar alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Considera leer [ask], editar y mostrar que llevas ya que tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y puede acabar cerrada

Comment: Yo te colaboro, solo dame dos dias

Comment: Puedes revisar como funciona drag and drop, es una de las opciones para arrastrar elementos.

Comment: Sí tnemos ydea, pero queremos ver que has intentado tú para poderte ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás ya hayas encontrado la respuesta pero tienes muchas opciones para realizar esta acción, lo mas común es utilizar las librarías existentes, pero de igual manera te recomiendo aprender como se hace con javascript de manera pura.

Para eso te recomiendo leer la documentación primero [developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) 
Y un ejemplo de [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

Con eso ya te puedes hacer una idea de como funciona, y te puedes lanzar a utilizar librerias como [JqueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) o tambien tienes muchas mas opciones como por ejemplo [Draggable](https://shopify.github.io/draggable/), [InteractJS](https://interactjs.io/), [SortableJS](https://sortablejs.github.io/sortablejs/) entre [otros](https://openbase.io/packages/top-javascript-drag-and-drop-libraries) mas.

Comment: todo ok. pero me tope con la sorpresa que en los dispositivos moviles no funciona :(

Comment: Encontre este [drag and drop](http://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/demo/), tal vez te sea de utilidad